# EXPLAIN filter value changes on changing column

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, mysql-5.7

I have experienced a strange behavior in MySQL 5.7

```
SELECT orderId
  FROM `order`
 WHERE vendor = 11 AND status >= 0 AND city = 1 
   AND created_date >= '2020-12-01' AND created_date <= '2020-12-31'
```

[image: Query 1]

```
SELECT userId
  FROM `order`
 WHERE vendor = 11 AND status >= 0 AND city = 1 
   AND created_date >= '2020-12-01' AND created_date <= '2020-12-31'
```

[image: Filter]

I have a composite index on all the 4 columns
INDEX is `vendor_city_date (vendor, city, created_date, status)`.

But for some columns I get a filter of 50 for others I get a filter of 5.55.

This is the structure of the table it has 50 other columns I have removed those.

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (
 `orderId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `vendor` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `offer` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `city` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `offset` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `payment` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `created_date` date NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`orderId`),
 KEY `city_id` (`city`),
 KEY `user_id` (`userId`),
 KEY `status` (`status`),
 KEY `vendor` (`vendor`),
 KEY `user_status` (`userId`,`status`),
 KEY `vendor_city_date` (`vendor`,`city`,`created_date`,`status`) USING BTREE
);
```

Comment: Do you have any other indices on that table?  What's the ***full*** table deifition?  *(All the keys, contraints, etc)*

Comment: @MatBailie I have updated my question. Added the table structure

Comment: Not immediately related to the question, but 50 columns in one table sounds like a lot. Are you sure your database is properly normalized?

Comment: `OrderId` is the primary key.  In MySQL, it is often included in the index implicitly.

Comment: @GordonLinoff for `city` column also it is giving  `filter: 50`

Comment: What is the difference between the two queries?  In the two `EXPLAINs`, which index did it pick?

Comment: @RickJames for both queries, it picked `vendor_city_date` index

Comment: The title says you changed a _column name_?  Which column?

Comment: @RickJames I have changed the title, I have changed the column, and I'm getting different filter value.

Comment: @aRvi - I still see absolutely no difference between the two queries.  Is something else different, like the version number?

Comment: no, I executed the query on the same MySQL server